# Using Ins Amp as current monitor

Tags: current-measurement, instrumentation-amplifier

I am using a ready board (using AD620) in my circuit as a current monitor.I have set the gain of the board to 10x.

1)My first question,is this a right way to approach the problem.My trials show that it is working with an error of about 2~5% over the range of currents from 0~300mA.

2)I have two loads ,drawing ca. 272mA and 27.2mA simultaneously.When I disconnect 272mA load,I find that the output from the 27.2mA rises by 2mA (20mV).The voltage at the shunt,does not change,only the amplified voltage at the output.I swapped the loads,and found that the same behavior is on both the channels.

TIA.

[image]

[image]

Comment: (1) You've omitted the link to the board datasheet. (2) The disjointed schematic is hard to follow. (3) You have +60V connected to GND. (4) What are R11 and R12 for? (5) The AD620s seem to be powered from +5V but have negative voltages on their S- inputs. Is that allowed. (6) "*I find that the output from the 27.2mA ...*". That doesn't make sense. Edit required.

Comment: Are you trying to make a hi-side current measurement?

Comment: 1) There is no board datasheet/schematic,as such.I just purchased it from a website.I can give you an explanation,if it helps.It seems to be a generic AD620 circuit.7660 is for getting a -5V,from the 5V,to have a dual supply for AD620.LM358 is for buffering the input to REF pin,and also for buffering the output from the AD650. +60V is floating with respect to the 5V GND.R11 and R12 are load resistors which i am using in lieu of the actual load,which will also be a resistive load.

Comment: Yes,I am trying to make a Hi Side current measurement.

Comment: 6) "I find that the output from the 27.2mA ...". That doesn't make sense. Yes,that's the part I am having trouble with.I will trace and post the schematic,if it helps.Thanks for the replies.